# Upload a json file in php

Tags: php, uploads, json

I'm trying to upload a json file through PHP. This is the code that i have yet.

```
if( isset( $_POST['upload'] )) {
    $target = "/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']) ;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target))
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

I have Browse button and an Import button, and when i press Import, it doesn't say anything.

```
 echo '<div class="wrap">';
echo "<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input type='file' name='upload' value='Upload' id='upload' /></form>";
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="wrap">';
echo "<form action='' method='post'><input class='button-secondary' type='submit' name='import' value='Import' id='import' /></form>";
echo '</div>';
```

This is the code for the buttons.

Any idea how could I solve this issue?

Comment: Where is this code being placed? A meta box? A custom admin page? A frontend template?

Comment: The buttons are in a subpage of a plugin.

Comment: Can you expand your code a little so we can see the context? It's not clear which hook the above is running on or what comes before and after it

Answer (score 0):

You have the browse button and the import button in two different HTML form elements. Don't do that, put them in the same `<form>`.